# scrapy json output all items on one line

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to get my output to look like the following in json format.

```
{"loser": "De Schepper K." ,"winner": "Herbert P.", "url":
"https://www.sofascore.com/tennis/2018-02-07"}
```

But I'm currently getting individual lines for each loser item and winner item. I would like both winner and loser to be on the same line with the url.

```
{"loser": "De Schepper K.", "url": 
"https://www.sofascore.com/tennis/2018-02-07"}
{"winner": "Herbert P.", "url": 
"https://www.sofascore.com/tennis/2018-02-07"}
{"loser": "Sugita Y.", "url": 
 "https://www.sofascore.com/tennis/2018-02-07"}
```

I'm not sure if it's my selectors that's causing this behaviour but I'd like to know how I can customise the pipelines so the loser, winner and date are all on the same json line

I've never extracted json format before so it's new to me. 
How do you specify what json keys and values will be on each line using custom pipeline?

I also tried to use csv item exporter to do this and got strange behaviour too. ref
[Scrapy output is showing empty rows per column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48797819/scrapy-output-is-showing-empty-rows-per-column)

Here's my spider.py

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from scrapejs.items import SofascoreItemLoader
from scrapy import Spider

import json
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest

    class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "jsscraper"

    start_urls = ["https://www.sofascore.com/tennis/2018-02-07"]


    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url=url,
                            callback=self.parse,
                            endpoint='render.html',
                            args={'wait': 1.5})



    def parse(self, response):
            for row in response.css('.event-team'):
                    il = SofascoreItemLoader(selector=row)
                    il.add_css('winner' , '.event-team:nth-
                      child(2)::text')
                    il.add_css('loser' , '.event-team:nth-
                    child(1)::text')
                    il.add_value('url', response.url)

                    yield il.load_item()
```

items.py

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import TakeFirst, MapCompose
from operator import methodcaller
from scrapy import Spider, Request, Selector

class SofascoreItem(scrapy.Item):
    loser = scrapy.Field()
    winner = scrapy.Field()
    url = scrapy.Field()



class SofascoreItemLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_item_class = SofascoreItem
    default_input_processor = MapCompose(methodcaller('strip'))
    default_output_processor = TakeFirst()
```

pipeline.py

```
import json
import codecs
from collections import OrderedDict

class JsonPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.file = codecs.open('data_utf8.json' , 'w' , 
        encoding='utf-8')

    def process_item(self , item , spider):
        line = json.dumps(OrderedDict(item) , ensure_ascii=False , 
        sort_keys=False) + "\n"
        self.file.write(line)
        return item

    def close_spider(self , spider):
        self.file.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're looping over `.event-team` elements.
One of these elements can only be the winner or the loser, so you get an item for each.

What you should be doing instead is loop over elements containing both (`.list-event` seems like a good candidate), and extract both the winner and loser from those.

This way, you'd have one loop per event, and as a result, one item per event.

Comment: Thanks a lot! that fixed my issue. It was the selectors all along.

Answer (score 1):

So I relooked your question, and I now find where the problem is:

```
for row in response.css('.event-team'):
```

With the above line, you will get many Selectors(or a SelectorList). However, in each Selector or row, you can only get one Field: winner or loser. You can't get them both. 
[image]

That's why there will be empty rows in your output.

Solution: try the following line:

```
for row in response.css('div[class=“cell__section--main s-tennisCell curb-width”]')
```